# jQuery comma separated phone numbers mask input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, mask

Does anybody knows any good plugin (maybe jQuery) for comma separated phone numbers mask input?

There are a lot of mask input plugins, but I cannot find plugin for multi values field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meioMask is excellent. Open Source. Very clear documentation.

http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it by yourself.

You only has to work with .change() jQuery event.

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
    $text = $(this).text();
    /*DO SOME STUFF*/
    $(this).text($text);
});
```

More information about .change() event, [here](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

More information about .text() function, [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/).